# Script to close program that's causing CPU overheat

Tags: c#, vb.net, batch-file, vbscript, batch-processing

You see i use CoreTemp program to monitor CPU heat, this program allows you to run a script or a program when the CPU temp reaches a specified value..

What i want is that when the CPU temp reaches a certain value, the process that has the most CPU usage is to be closed!!

**In other words, I need a Script/program that automatically scans the processes and force close the process that has the highest CPU usage..**

Thanks!

Comment: There is three problems with this. Firstly a program running all the time like this could make the CPU hotter its self. Secondly programs can go from 100% to 1% in less than a second so what if the program that is causing the problem drops and the wrong program is killed. Finally is you are moving files and the CPU gets too hot and it kills explorer. This would make your computer somewhat unusable till is is started again, And killing it during files been moved can damage files too.

Comment: Define "has the most CPU usage". Do you mean at this point, over the last minute or what's your definition? There are so many things that could go wrong with this approach, but if you want to do this at least you have to come up with a workable definition of what processes you want to target.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

**Check the prog with the higher Memory Use :**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "skip=4 tokens=1-5 delims= " %%a in ('tasklist') do (
set $Size=00000000%%e
set $Size=!$size:.=!
set #!$size:~-10!=%%a
)
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set #') do (set $Bigger=%%a)

echo taskkill /IM !$Bigger!
```

**Check the process with the higher CPU use :**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "skip=2 tokens=1-2 delims= " %%a in ('"wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get Name,PercentProcessorTime"') do (
if "%%a"=="_Total" goto:next
set #%%b=%%a
)    
:next    

for /f "tokens=1-2 delims==" %%a in ('set #') do (
set $Bigger=%%b
set $Value=%%a
)
if "!$Value!"=="#0" goto:nothing
echo taskkill /IM !$Bigger!.exe [!$Value:#=!%%]
goto:eof

:nothing
Echo CPU IS INACTIVE
```

If the output is OK for you remove the `ECHO` on the last line

You can ameliorate the script. In case you have two processus with the same name you have to work with th PID of the process in place of the name. Because the programm will return program#1, program#2, etc.. That's just the base script.
And Like  @09stephenb commented you have to go carrefully with such a script....

Comment: Thanks for answering, Only this is working for the Memory Usage, it does return the process that has the highest Memory Usage, But what i want is the exact same thing but For CPU Usage !!

Answer (score 0):

I started working on this for you but I have to leave. It's mostly complete so I'm just gonna give you what I have so far and let you take it from there.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set proc=Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process
set "wmi=wmic path %proc% get Name^,PercentProcessorTime"
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%a in ('"%wmi%"^|findstr /i /v /g:Excludes.txt') do (
   for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%b in ( "%%a" ) do if %%b NEQ 0 echo %%a
)
```

Create a file called Excludes.txt and make sure it's in the same dir of your script.

```
"System Idle Process"
Idle
explorer.exe
taskmgr.exe
lsass.exe
csrss.exe
smss.exe
winlogon.exe
svchost.exe
services.exe
Core Temp
_Total
```